# PHP Search with SQL (LIKE) doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I want to create a search page for my website, but my SQL query doesn't return what I want.
This is my SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%" . Addslashes($_GET['s']) . "%' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date DESC lIMIT 0, 4;
```

But it only return the published posts, it doesn't return the searched post
This is my search page : https://lite.the-scientist.fr/search

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: You have tagged this with [tag:sql-server] but the `LIMIT` clause should be for [tag:mysql]

Comment: a) what do you get and what do you expect to get? Your query can only return published posts, so I'm not sure why returning the published posts is wrong.  b) `Addslashes` is a really bad fix for what @Chris meant. Please use [binding](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.phpbinding). Your problem will probably go away then if it is related to the content of `s` (but you have to add the `%` before binding, not to your query).